# iOS - Custom UISwitch in Class

Tags: ios, swift, uiswitch

version: Xcode 12.3

My project uses `UISwitch` heavily. Therefore, I am creating a custom Class to customize it.

I would like to set `UISwitch` default `thumbTintColor` and `backgroundColor`, and update these colors when the switch is togged on (`isOn` property).

I've found a solution but it does not work when I return to the `viewController`. The switch doesn't retain the setting:

```
subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = UIColor.white
```

I can't set `isOn` because it's read-only property.

Is there anyway that I can set the value change? I want something like below in the customSwitch Class:

> Switch off: thumbTintColor = UIColor.yellow, backgroundColor =
> UIcolor.black
>
> Switch on: thumbTintColor = UIColor.red, backgroundColor =
> UIcolor.white

below is my custom Class, can anyone help? thanks.

```
import Foundation

@IBDesignable
class CustomSwitch: UISwitch {     
    private var previousValue = false
    private var returnPreviousValue = false
    
    override var isOn: Bool {
        return returnPreviousValue ? previousValue : super.isOn
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        
        previousValue = isOn
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(_didChange), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        
        addTarget(self, action: #selector(_didChange), for: .valueChanged)
    }
    
    
    
    override func setOn(_ on: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setOn(on, animated: animated)
        
        previousValue = on
    }
    
    @objc func _didChange() {
        let isOn = self.isOn
        
        if isOn == previousValue {
            return
        }
        
        returnPreviousValue = true
        willChangeValue(forKey: "on")
        returnPreviousValue = false
        
        previousValue = isOn
        didChangeValue(forKey: "on")
    }
}
```

Comment: isOn is not read only. So there is another problem. Why don't you simply: subviews[0].subviews[0].backgroundColor = isOn ? UIColor.white : UIColor.black

Answer (score 1):

#### Code

```
@IBDesignable
class CustomSwitch: UISwitch {
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        self.initialSetUp()
    }
    
    convenience init() {
        self.init(frame: .zero)
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        self.initialSetUp()
    }
    
    private func initialSetUp() {
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(refreshUI), for: .valueChanged)
        self.refreshUI()
    }
    
    @objc private func refreshUI() {
        /// Be aware that this is more of a hack than a solution
        /// And can break in any upcoming release
        let targetSubview = self.subviews.first?.subviews.first
        
        if self.isOn {
            self.thumbTintColor = .red
            targetSubview?.backgroundColor = .white
        }
        else {
            self.thumbTintColor = .yellow
            targetSubview?.backgroundColor = .black
        }
    }
    
}
```

#### Usage

```
let customSwitch = CustomSwitch()
self.view.addSubview(customSwitch)
customSwitch.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
    customSwitch.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor),
    customSwitch.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor),
])
```

Comment: Thanks Tarun, your solution works great. However, I try to leave current view controller and when I return to it, the switch's "Off" state color change to red on thumbTint, white on background.(it should be yellow&black ). It didn't init or enter refreshUI(), how can I solve this issue?